# Rake task to change all occurances of a method in a project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, rake, rake-task

I am trying to write a rake task to rename all occurrences of a method in a ruby project. I have achieved this using the following command from the command line.

Basically

```
retention.group_by('bla').count
```

needs to be changed to

```
retention.group_by('bla').size
```

I managed to achieve this uisng the following from the command line

```
find . -name \*.rb -exec ruby -i -p -e "gsub(/(group_by(\(([^\)]+)\))).count/, '\1.size')" \;
```

I am now trying to do this from a rake task to make it straight forward to change in all our projects. Which is the easiest / most elegant way to do this ? Think I am close, its just selecting all files in a project directory I am stuck on.

Comment: Why not do a find all with your IDE and using your Regex to find every places where you use `.count` instead of `size` ?

Comment: I need this be changed in a number of rails clients so i need to make it as straight forward as possible

Comment: I would use the File library to open each file and read the lines to look for that pattern. http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/File.html

Answer (score 0):

This did the trick

```
 namespace :rename do

  task :gb_count_rename do
    Dir.glob("**/*.rb").each do |file_name|
      text = File.read(file_name)
      content = text.gsub(/(group_by(\(([^\)]+)\))).count/, '\1.size')
      File.open(file_name, "w") { |file| file << content }
    end
  end

end
```